# How to change the default ownership of a redis dumpdb file?

Tags: permissions, redis, backup

The default `dump.rdb` file is created redis saves to disk, and the default ownership is `redis:redis` with `660` permission. This is refershed **everytime** redis performs automatic backups.

How could I set the ownership to, saying `redis:admin`?

Answer (score 1):

How are you starting `redis`? I have a `/etc/init.d/redis-server` script which is below.

You can set the `$USER` and `$GROUP` to run the redis binary as. When doing a dump Redis will use these user+group permissions.

```
#!/bin/bash

#! /bin/sh
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:             redis-server
# Required-Start:       $syslog
# Required-Stop:        $syslog
# Should-Start:         $local_fs
# Should-Stop:          $local_fs
# Default-Start:        2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:         0 1 6
# Short-Description:    redis-server - Persistent key-value db
# Description:          redis-server - Persistent key-value db
### END INIT INFO

PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
DAEMON=/usr/local/bin/redis-server
DAEMON_ARGS=/etc/redis.conf
NAME=redis-server
DESC=redis-server
PIDFILE=/var/run/redis.pid
USER=myuser
GROUP=mygroup

test -x $DAEMON || exit 0
test -x $DAEMONBOOTSTRAP || exit 0

set -e

case "$1" in
  start)
        echo -n "Starting $DESC: "
        touch $PIDFILE
        chown $USER:$GROUP $PIDFILE
        if start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --umask 007 --pidfile $PIDFILE --chuid $USER:$GROUP --exec $DAEMON -- $DAEMON_ARGS
        then
                echo "$NAME."
        else
                echo "failed"
        fi
        ;;
  stop)
        echo -n "Stopping $DESC: "
        if start-stop-daemon --stop --retry 10 --quiet --oknodo --pidfile $PIDFILE --exec $DAEMON
        then
                echo "$NAME."
        else
                echo "failed"
        fi
        rm -f $PIDFILE
        ;;

  restart|force-reload)
        ${0} stop
        ${0} start
        ;;
  *)
        echo "Usage: /etc/init.d/$NAME {start|stop|restart|force-reload}" >&2
        exit 1
        ;;
esac

exit 0
```